# Burning a DVD Disc

Tags: dvd, burning

If I download Ubuntu O.S. and burn a DVD on my windows 7 64 bit machine, will that DVD install on my older laptop? Windows XP 32 bit.
Thanks, Gary.

Comment: Yes, if you download and burn the 32bit ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can able to boot from the ubuntu-live-dvd on older laptop only if it has a dvd drive and boot from dvd option in bios.

Also [checks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) that your older laptop supports Ubuntu or not.

Comment: Note that the older computer must have enough power to run Ubuntu.